# Room cannot verify the data integrity and Crashes on Empty Data

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-room

I am working on Android Application in Which I am getting specific Data from Room Database by specific path in the Storage. My App Got Crashes as It does not have Any Data in the Storage and the `Logcat` gives me this..

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Room cannot verify the data integrity. Looks like you've changed schema but forgot to update the version number. You can simply fix this by increasing the version number.
    at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.checkIdentity(RoomOpenHelper.java:154)
    at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.onOpen(RoomOpenHelper.java:135)
    at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onOpen(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:195)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:428)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:317)
    at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:145)
    at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:106)
    at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.inTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:476)
    at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotSuspendingTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:281)
    at com.maximus.technologies.views.activities.scanneddatabase.TodoDaoScanned_Impl.getAllScan(TodoDaoScanned_Impl.java:152)
    at com.maximus.technologies.views.fragments.scanhistorypackage.QRRetrievingScanClassPresenter$getAllDatFromDatabase$1.invokeSuspend(QRRetrievingScanClassPresenter.kt:29)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:241)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:594)
```

The Above Error or crash Only occurs as the app dont have any data in Storage. But as I put a Data the Crash Problem Get Resolved.

I am not able to Understand what the Problem actually is...

Here is My Room Database Class..

```
@Database(
entities = [TodoEntity::class,TodoEntityScanned::class],
version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun TodoDao(): TodoDao
    abstract fun TodoDaoScanned(): TodoDaoScanned

object DatabaseBuilder {
    private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null

    fun getInstance(context: Context): AppDatabase {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized(AppDatabase::class) {
                INSTANCE = buildRoomDB(context)
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE!!
    }

    private fun buildRoomDB(context: Context) =
        Room.databaseBuilder(
            context.applicationContext,
            AppDatabase::class.java,
            "mindorks-example-coroutines"
        ).build()
}
```

}

Room Database Retrieving Interface where app Crashes on `getall()`

```
 override fun getAllDatFromDatabase(appDatabasescanned: AppDatabase) {
    var list = listOf<TodoEntityScanned>()
    try {
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
                list = appDatabasescanned.TodoDaoScanned().getAllScan()
                Log.d("hello","hello")
                mView.showAllData(list)
       }
    }
    catch (e:Exception){
        Log.d("get hello",e.toString())
    }
}
```

The `getAll` lies in Dao Class

```
interface TodoDao {
@Query("SELECT * FROM tablefilepaths")
fun getAll(): List<TodoEntity>

@Query("SELECT * FROM tablefilepaths WHERE imagespath LIKE :title")
fun findByTitle(title: String): TodoEntity

@Insert
fun insertpaths(todo: TodoEntity)

@Delete
fun deletepaths(todo: TodoEntity)

@Query("DELETE FROM tablefilepaths WHERE id = :noteId")
fun deleteNoteById(noteId: Int)

@Update
fun updateTodo(vararg todos: TodoEntity)}
```

Here is My Fragment Class Where I am Setting data in `RecyclerView`

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    recyclerviewcreatehistory?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    recyclerviewcreatehistory?.setHasFixedSize(true)
    filefetch()
    customAdaptercreatehistory = CustomAdapterCreateHistory(this.context ?: return, charItemcreate!!,this)
    recyclerviewcreatehistory?.adapter = customAdaptercreatehistory
}

fun filefetch() {
    val noteDatabase: AppDatabase = AppDatabase.DatabaseBuilder.getInstance(requireContext())
    retrivingpresenter = QRRetrievingClassPresenter(this)
    retrivingpresenter!!.getAllDatFromDatabase(noteDatabase)
}
override fun showAllData(note_list: List<TodoEntity>) {
    if (note_list is ArrayList<*>) {
    val arraylist = note_list as ArrayList<TodoEntity>
    charItemcreate=arraylist
    }
    if (charItemcreate.isEmpty()){
    }else{
        customAdaptercreatehistory?.updateUsers(note_list as ArrayList<TodoEntity>)
        customAdaptercreatehistory?.notifyDataSetChanged()
       // Log.d("hello", note_list[0].imagesPathData)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do some checks in your getAllDatFromDatabase() inside your coroutine. I guess list variable equals null or something like that. You should check if there are any files and if not you need to put there something else.